# Import error with module in Python 2.7

Tags: python, import, importerror, xlrd

I've spent the better part of an afternoon trying to import the xlrd module, it works when i do it in the shell but when i try to run any file I get an import error.
Please could somebody provide a solution? (I'm a beginner, so please be excruciatingly specific)

This code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

os.chdir("C:/Users/User/Documents/Python/xlrd")

import xlrd
```

returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Programs\Radiocarbon27.py", line 4 in <module>

import xlrd
ImportError: No module named xlrd
```

The path of the setup.py which contains the setup.py file is C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\xlrddocs

thanks!

Comment: You want to install the module, not chdir into the directory containing it and importing from there. Run `setup.py install`.

Comment: Thank you so much! At the lab I need to run the software on a mac, what would be the equivalent action?

Comment: You'd do the same thing.

Comment: setup.py files are python. They work on any machine with python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the `Start button`, click `All Programs`, click `Accessories`, and then click `Command Prompt`.

Type `Python` then hit enter.

If you get the following, then you have to setup your environment variables.

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

If Python started, then you do not have to setup your environment variables.
Close the command prompt and open another one.

In the new command prompt type: `cd C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\xlrddocs`

Then type: `Python setup.py install`

That's it! Now in your .py file type:

```
import os
import xlrd
```

Answer (score 1):

The xlrd package is not installed. 
For example, you can do

```
$yum install python27_xlrd-0.9.3
```